# Pygame slideshow delay anormally long

Tags: python, pygame, framebuffer, libvlc, pygame-surface

I'm setting up a Slideshow system mixing images and videos, from a directory.
I'm using a Raspberry Pi B, pygame and vlc.
I didn't install X so everything happens in framebuffer.

My actual code is working but :

- The 4 seconds delay is not respected. The image is displayed +- 11 seconds.
- One of the images witch has nothing particular, is displayed much longer, +- 1m30. (my real problem)

I tried a bash script with fbi, fim, vlc without suitable result. The closest was with vlc but it takes too long to render an image in framebuffer.

I'm quite new to pygame. Here is the code:

```py
import pygame
import sys
import time
import vlc
import os


filesdir = '/home/pi/SMBmount/'

pygame.init()

size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    # For every file in filesdir :
    for filename in os.listdir(filesdir):
        filenamelower = filename.lower()

        # If image:
        if filenamelower.endswith('.png') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpg') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpeg'):
            fullname = filesdir + filename
            img = pygame.image.load(fullname)
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img, size)
            imgrect = img.get_rect()

            screen.fill(black)
            screen.blit(img, imgrect)
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
            pygame.display.flip()

            time.sleep(4)

        # Elif video:
        elif filenamelower.endswith('.mp4') or filenamelower.endswith('.mkv') or filenamelower.endswith('.avi'):
            fullname = filesdir + filename
            # Create instane of VLC and create reference to movie.
            vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--aout=adummy")
            media = vlcInstance.media_new(fullname)

            # Create new instance of vlc player
            player = vlcInstance.media_player_new()

            # Load movie into vlc player instance
            player.set_media(media)

            # Start movie playback
            player.play()

            # Do not continue if video not finished
            while player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
                # Quit if keyboard pressed during video
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        pygame.display.quit()
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
            player.stop()

        # Quit if keyboard pressed during video
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

I'm open to any alternative able to work with pictures AND videos.

EDIT: It was finally the time it takes to pygame to resize the (next) image with `pygame.transform.scale()`.

Is there any way to optimise that ? Like for example, to print fullscreen without resizing the large images ?

Comment: About this `One of the images witch has nothing particular, is displayed much longer`: there must be something particular, othewise the very long time cannot be explained. Is always the same image which stay longer? Do you have a very big image in your slideshow?

Comment: It's a PNG, like several others. It's actually the smallest of the images : 35k. The dimensions are 1451x816.
Do you think it can be the scaling of the next image (3,3M, 3000x1687) with `pygame.transform.scale()` who takes ages ?

Comment: It was indeed the reason.

Comment: Yes it is. scaling large pictures takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what were the issues, with the help of [Valentino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10426037/valentino).
He helped me to optimize the code to improve the loading times of every image, that fixed the first issue.

[See his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292619/7504927).

Additionnally, I added a block of code :

```py
# If image is not same dimensions
if imgrect.size != size:
    img = Image.open(fullname)
    img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(fullname, optimize=True, quality=95)
    img = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
    imgrect = img.get_rect()
```

If the picture is not the screen resolution, I use Pillow (PIL) to resize and reduce the color palette to 8-bit (256 colors).
It reduces file sizes significantly (especially for big files) and allow pygame to load the image faster.
It fixed the second issue.

For those interested, the full code is :

```py
import pygame
import sys
import vlc
import os
import re
from PIL import Image


filesdir = '/home/pi/SMBmount/'

imgexts = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
videxts = ['mp4', 'mkv', 'avi']

time = 5  # Time to display every img

#filtering out non video and non image files in the directory using regex
showlist = [filename for filename in os.listdir(filesdir) if re.search('[' + '|'.join(imgexts + videxts) + ']$', filename.lower())]

pygame.init()

size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    # For every file in filesdir :
    for filename in showlist:
        filenamelower = filename.lower()

        # If image:
        if filenamelower.endswith('.png') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpg') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpeg'):
            fullname = filesdir + filename
            img = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
            imgrect = img.get_rect()

            # If image is not same dimensions
            if imgrect.size != size:
                img = Image.open(fullname)
                img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                img.save(fullname, optimize=True, quality=95)
                img = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
                imgrect = img.get_rect()

            screen.blit(img, imgrect)
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
            pygame.display.flip()

        # Elif video:
        elif filenamelower.endswith('.mp4') or filenamelower.endswith('.mkv') or filenamelower.endswith('.avi'):
            fullname = filesdir + filename
            # Create instane of VLC and create reference to movie.
            vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--aout=adummy")
            media = vlcInstance.media_new(fullname)

            # Create new instance of vlc player
            player = vlcInstance.media_player_new()

            # Load movie into vlc player instance
            player.set_media(media)

            # Start movie playback
            player.play()

            # Do not continue if video not finished
            while player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
                # Quit if keyboard pressed during video
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        pygame.display.quit()
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
            player.stop()

        clock.tick(1 / time)  # framerate = 0.25 means 1 frame each 4 seconds

        # Quit if keyboard pressed during video
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the behaviour without the images and the videos, but here a couple of advices which should help in speed up the code when displaying images.

1. Do not use `time.sleep()`. It will freeze the game for the given time, so all calculations are done outside this time window, consuming more time. Better to use [pygame time Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock). From the docs of its `tick()` method:

   > If you pass the optional framerate argument the function will delay to keep the game running slower than the given ticks per second. This can be used to help limit the runtime speed of a game. By calling Clock.tick(40) once per frame, the program will never run at more than 40 frames per second.

   The `tick()` method should be called once per iteration in the main loop, so better to not put it inside an `if` statement.
2. Here:

   ```
   screen.fill(black)
   screen.blit(img, imgrect)
   ```

   The first line `screen.fill(black)` is completely useless: you are redrawing the whole surface in the second line covering all the black background, since the image is rescaled to the screen size. You can safely `blit` the image without filling the background with black.
   This will save time, because each time you use `blit` or `fill`, `pygame` in background does a lot of operation on the Surface to change the color of the pixels (the more the pixels changed, the longer the time needed).

   This of course if any of the images you load has an alpha channel. If you have pictures with alpha channel, you need to paint black the background before. To save time, I suggest to remove the alpha channel from the images using another program.
3. `pygame.transform.scale()` requires time, especially if you have very large picture. Try to rescale your image with another program and load in pygame images of size the closer possible to your screen.
4. When loading the images, add `.convert()`. This will make blitting faster. Should be: `img = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()`.

In the end, your code should look like:

```
imgexts = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
videxts = ['mp4', 'mkv']

#filtering out non video and non image files in the directory using regex
#remember to import re module
showlist = [filename for filename in os.listdir(filesdir) if re.search('[' + '|'.join(imgexts + videxts) + ']$', filename.lower())]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    # For every file in filesdir :
    for filename in showlist:
        filenamelower = filename.lower()

        # If image:
        if filenamelower.endswith('.png') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpg') or filenamelower.endswith('.jpeg'):
            #all your stuff but NOT the time.sleep()

        elif filenamelower.endswith('.mp4') or filenamelower.endswith('.mkv') or filenamelower.endswith('.avi'):
            #unchanged here

        clock.tick(0.25) #framerate = 0.25 means 1 frame each 4 seconds
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #unchanged here
```

Comment: Thanks for these awesome tips, I can totally tell the difference. I finally use Pillow to resize, compress and save the images.
However it can still be long to load my resized PNG (1.4Mo) (it's a Pi B..), as a result,  the previous image is displayed from 10 to 35 seconds instead of 5s.
Here is my actual code : https://framagit.org/SecT0uch/slideshow/blob/master/Slideshow.py. Do you think I should reduce the quality of img.save(fullname, optimize=True, quality=95)? I was thinking 80 or 85

Comment: Reducing the quality may help in saving time. You can try and see. Is your current code overwriting the images on the disk if they are not of the same size of the screen? This may be a bit dangerous, you will lose the original image.

Comment: Yes it replaces the file, not exactly on the SD but on a mounted SMB share. It's not a problem since all the files in the directory are copies and original files safely saved somewhere else. I'll try to try to reduce and test ipage quality tomorrow.